# Why doesn't my base64 'image64' appear in my print preview (and printed) html document built in JS?

Tags: javascript, base64, print-preview

Dears,
Why doesn't the 'image64' base64 variable of a gif image (normaly returned by a script (Ajax) to a calling Javascript function) appear in the print preview (and printed) html document (normaly prepared in the same JS function) ?
Windows 11, Edge, Chrome. See my source below. Thanks for help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Test_3.php : Picture in confirmation document issue.</title>
    </head>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function printConfo() {
            var image64 = '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';
            var doc_print = window.open("", "Confirmation");
            doc_print.document.open();
            doc_print.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en-us> <head>');
            doc_print.document.write('<meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />');
            doc_print.document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">');
            doc_print.document.write('<title>Confirmation</title> </head>');
            doc_print.document.write('<body style="font-family:verdana; font-size:12px;" onload="self.print(); self.close();">');
            doc_print.document.write('<br /> <br /> <h4><center>CONFIRMATION</center></h4> <br />');
            doc_print.document.write('<center> <img src="data:image/gif;base64,' + image64 + '" height="180" width="180" alt="BelgianFlag" > </center>');
            doc_print.document.write('<h1></h1> Blablabla ...');
            doc_print.document.write('</body> </html>');
            doc_print.print();
            doc_print.close();
            }
    </script>
    
    <body>
        <h2>Picture in print preview document</h2>
        <input id="submit" type="button" value=" Print confirmation " onclick="printConfo()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm just trying to build (in a JS function) and propose a confirmation html document to my clients.

Comment: Wow, there's a lot wrong with this... For starters, you cannot reliably set a header in PHP when you've already output something (the doctype line).  Next, `document.write` really should not be used.  Ideally, your pop-up window would just load a URL.  Though if you must, you can always set the contents of the document... but don't use `document.write()`!  Next, don't base64-encode your image... there's no reason to!  It adds 33% overhead in size and a lot of memory.  And, the `<center>` tag has been deprecated a very long time.  Several more issues...

Comment: I don't really know what it is that you're trying to do, but I'd suggest nuking this and starting over from scratch.  If you're trying to do a print preview, really only the browser can do that anyway.  You could set your CSS in such a way that looks printable, but you don't then know what size paper or printer margin settings are configured.  So, leave that stuff up to the browser.  You **can** still configure your CSS to look good printed though.  Just don't try to make your own print preview.

Comment: (I first moved my <!DOCTYPE html > line AFTER my php block).

Comment: As I said yesterday, I used the document.write method in my JS function (after calling a php Ajax script to record the customer's data) because the confirmation document then composed and offered to the customer for printing depends on several values returned by this script.
Meanwhile, I've just noticed that the image I was trying to produce in my print preview finally appears after disabling lines 28 and 29 (doc_print.print(); and doc_print.close();).
But you're right, I'm still going to investigate the problem solution by creating a new html page ...
Thanks again, Brad.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the base64 image can be huge in size, so it needs time to load, I simplified the code and added a short delay before triggering the print action. This delay allows time for the image to be loaded properly before printing. Adjust the delay value (in milliseconds) as needed based on your image loading time. This approach ensures that the image is included in the print preview.

- Change the last two lines of your function to below:

```js
doc_print.document.close(); // open document must be closed

setTimeout(function() {
  doc_print.print();
  doc_print.close();
}, 1000); // Adjust the delay as needed
```

I hope that help.